# Is the javascript Date() incompatible with some browsers?

Tags: javascript, date, math, browser

I am using this function to display the number of days that have passed since beginning of 2016:

```
function setDays() {
    var days = Math.floor((new Date() - new Date('2016-01-01T00:00:01.000Z')) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24);
    document.getElementById("days").innerHTML = days.toLocaleString();
}
```

I always thought that it was working without problems. However, I recently discovered that on the browser of an HTC Wildfire it produces `NaN`.

What is wrong here? How should I change my function?

Comment: Maybe it doesn't support ISO 8601 timestamps? You might try without the milliseconds part.

Comment: Date() is compatible with every browser. Your timestamp maybe isn't

Comment: Given that your date is constant, you might just want to use `1451606401000` directly.